# How to copy an Excel sheet with formulas between files?

Tags: excel, file

I have two Excel files: file1 with two Sheets (Sheet1 and Sheet2) and file2 with Sheet3.
Sheets 1 and 3 have the same structure but different data.
Sheet2 contains some formulas referring to Sheet1 like for example **"=Sheet1!A1"**.

I want to copy Sheet2 to file2 with the same formulas referring to Sheet3, but when I try to copy it, formulas change from **"=Sheet1!A1"** to **"=[file1.xls]Sheet1!A1"**.

How can I copy the whole sheet with the same formulas?

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure there is an explicit way to do this, however with some Find/Replace action you can work around this.

After you paste your new formulas into File2, do a find replace (<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>and select Replace).  Replace the file reference `[file1.xls]sheet1!` with `sheet3!` and this should remove that link.

While not 100% what you're asking, one way to copy exact formulas over (without changing the file or sheet references) is this:

Alternatively, you can put both the source and destination files into formula view mode (go to Formula on the ribbon --> Show Formulas or press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>`</kbd> (key that looks like backwards apostrophe)), then copy and paste the formulas from the first file to the second file, and exit formula view mode.

For your question, if you used this alternate method, you would still need to find/replace `Sheet1` with `Sheet3`.

Comment: @maro Note that as the new formulas should reference Sheet3 instead of sheet1, you should actually find & replace [file1.xls]sheet1! with sheet3!.

Comment: Thanks I updated my answer to include that.  I should probably drink my coffee!

Comment: When I try to use [CTRL]+[F] to replace that, every time I press "Replace" there is a popup window "Open a file" and everytime I have to click "Cancel". If there are 1000 cells with text to replace, there will be 1000 pop up windows that I have to close. So that way is not good...

Comment: What version of Excel are you using?  It's working fine for me in 2013.  Also did you try my second suggestion if the first one did not work?

Comment: 2007. Both are not working because in both of them I have to use Find And Replace function.

Comment: on the link https://spreadsheeto.com/show-formulas/ you can see how suggested alternative works.