# Copy Formulas in One excel Workpaper to another excel Workpaper without linking

Tags: vba, excel

I'm working on an Excel sheet that has 1026 cells ( 18 Columns+ 57 rows )
Each cell has a Formula.

I want to copy all Formulas for all 1026 cells and only the Formulas, and paste it in another Excel Workpaper.

I have tried using a special paste- Paste formulas and it linked me with the old workpaper which it's not what I want!

I'm only seeking to transfer the Formulas.

Any solutions ?

Comment: Duplicated of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31965152/how-to-copy-an-excel-sheet-with-formulas-between-files

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it this way, without any need to copy/paste:

```
destinationRange.Formula = sourceRange.Formula
```

It copies all the formulae in the source range, as is.

Comment: Thanks for your advance, where should I type this?

Comment: In VBA. Aren't you using VBA?