# Excel accessing separate sheet but keeps changing the reference automatically

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am trying to add a formula in an excel document which needs to access data from separate sheet (in the same book), but it keeps trying to refer to another book. I created the formulas in a different book for testing purposes, and got it working perfectly fine. There were two types of functions involved; one was a CountIf function for how many rows had a certain value in one column, and the other funcion was counting how many rows had a certain value in one column and another value in a different column. The formula I used for the first account was:

```
=COUNTIF(Sheet1!$H$2:H$65536, "Data Protection Awareness")
```

And the second formula was:

```
=COUNTIFS(Sheet1!I$2:$M$65536,"Column2",Sheet1!D$2:$H$65536,"Column1")
```

This is how I set them up in the test environment, and it worked fine. However, when I copied it into the other spreadsheet, it kept trying to reference back to the original spreadsheet, which was no use to me, so I copied the formulas into a Word document, changed all the examples of 'Sheet1' to 'Example Data', (=COUNTIF(Example [Data]Data!$H$2:H$65536, "Data Protection Awareness")) then copied it into the original spreadsheet, where it opened an 'Update Values: Data' Window.

I tried setting the source to the correct sheet, but this changed the formula to

```
=COUNTIF(Example [Data]Data!$H$2:H$65536, "Data Protection Awareness")
```

which returns a #NAME? error. I have also tried typing in the formula from scratch, with the same result.

How do I transfer the formulas successfully?

All data in this question is anonymised.

P.S. I have already looked around StackOverflow, and the closest I could find to what I am asking is [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31965152/how-to-copy-an-excel-sheet-with-formulas-between-files), which doesn't answer what I want to know.

Comment: Did you copy the formula from within the formula bar? or mistakenly copy the cell and paste the formula? this would potentially link back to the first workbook.

Comment: It is no longer linking back to the test spreadsheet. I wrote that as the title and submitted it before I noticed but found that i could not edit it.

Comment: @LambertBrother if you're referring to the title of your question, you can still [edit] it if you'd like to change the title or add more information

Answer (score 0):

The **Links Manager** is the best way to deal with **changing**, **breaking**, or **finding** external links.

---

### More information:

- Office.com : [**Find links (external references) in a workbook**](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/find-links-external-references-in-a-workbook-fcbf4576-3aab-4029-ba25-54313a532ff1)
- SuperUser : [**How to find broken links in Excel that can't be broken with 'Break Links'?**](https://superuser.com/a/721496/774713)

Comment: I tried this and deleted the links, but that has made no difference.

Answer (score 0):

I decided to try retyping the formulas from scratch, which worked onthis occasion for some reason. I think the key was to not copy and paste any of the actual formula, and instead only copy the text to be searched for and counted. This is all I did differently, and I hope reading this helps someone else out.